# Running into a problem when adding following line

Tags: javascript, calculator

I just started with Programming and watched this tutorial to build a Calculator with Java script: Here:(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j59qQ7YWLxw&t=1016s&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified)
I am almost at 24:12min in the video, but I encounter a problem after putting in the next line of code that he mentions after 24:12 min.

The UpdateDisplay function does not work properly for me. Before typing this "this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = this.previousOperand" everything works fine. But after that my numbers from my input dont get displayed anymore at all.

```js
class Calculator {
  constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {
    this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement;
    this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement;
    this.clear();
  }

  clear() {
    this.currentOperand = " ";
    this.previousOperand = " ";
    this.operation = undefined;
  }

  delete() {}

  appendNumber(number) {
    if ((number === ".") & this.currentOperand.includes(".")) return;
    this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString();
  }

  chooseOperation(operation) {
    this.operation = operation;
    this.previousOperand = this.currentOperand;
    this.currentOperand = "";
  }

  compute() {}

  updateDisplay() {
    this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText = this.currentOperand;
    this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = this.previousOperand;
  }
}

const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-number]");
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-operation]");
const equalsButton = document.querySelector("[data-equals]");
const delButton = document.querySelector("[data-delete]");
const allClearButton = document.querySelector("[data-allclear]");
const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector(
  "[data-previous-operand]"
);
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector(
  "[data-current-operand]"
);

const calculator = new Calculator(
  previousOperandTextElement,
  currentOperandTextElement
);

numberButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText);
    calculator.updateDisplay();
  });
});

operationButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    calculator.chooseOperation(button.innerText);
    calculator.updateDisplay();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="calculator-grid">
      <div class="output">
        <div data-previous-operand class="previous-operand">
          <div data-current-operand class="current-operand"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button data-allclear class="span-two">AC</button>
      <button data-delete>DEL</button>
      <button data-operation>÷</button>
      <button data-number>1</button>
      <button data-number>2</button>
      <button data-number>3</button>
      <button data-operation>*</button>
      <button data-number>4</button>
      <button data-number>5</button>
      <button data-number>6</button>
      <button data-operation>+</button>
      <button data-number>7</button>
      <button data-number>8</button>
      <button data-number>9</button>
      <button data-operation>-</button>
      <button data-number>.</button>
      <button data-number>0</button>
      <button data equals class="span-two">=</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Due to the fact of me being new to coding, I have not tried that much. But I rechecked my code but did    not find anything. Maybe I am clumsy but I am not sure. I tried using a boolean term to redefine my Display input bt that did not work out. ChatGpt could also not help.

Comment: Your `<div>` elements are nested so assigning the `innerText` removes the nested div. Perhaps they were intended to be siblings? `<div class = "output"><div data-previous-operand class="previous-operand"></div><div data-current-operand class = "current-operand"></div></div> `

Comment: @pilchard I tried your suggestion, but it "made it worse". The numbers and everything disappear if I do that. I am pretty sure the problem lies in that one function, I mentioned above in the JS file.

Comment: Correcting the HTML as I indicated 'works' [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jk2bngtv/). Assigning [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) *'...will replace the element's children with the given value'* so assigning `innerText` to the outer `data-previous-operand` div completely removes the inner `data-current-operand` div from the DOM.

Comment: If  you look at [the HTML in the video](https://youtu.be/j59qQ7YWLxw?si=t9ACmwFzDlHZSsmt) they are siblings as I recommended.